# Algorithm bubble sort

Tags: algorithm, bubble-sort

I have a question about a specific line in the bubble sort pseudo code.

[image]

I do not understand why `i = (n-1)`. does it mean that we should start to compare from the last element(1 and 7)?

Comment: Does that seem too obvious? Is that why you're asking? Because I would say yes that's exactly what it means: start from the end of the array and go to the beginning. But it'll never touch i = 0.

Answer (score 0):

No. The elements that are compared have indexes `j` and `j+1`. On the first iteration of the inner loop, `j==0`, so that you compare the elements `5` and `9`.

Spend some time "running" the algorithm by hand.

Answer (score 0):

No, your "bubble" sort algorithm always works from the front first. Even though the outer loop counts backwards, the variable `i` is never used to refer to an array index, only `j` is which is defined in the inner loop. Rather, the outer loop in your code is used to determine how high to count in your inner loops representing how many comparisons we need to preform.

---

The code works like so:
Assuming `A` holds our array: `[5,9,2,7,1]`,  "n" is 5, the length of the array, and our `swap` function works, the outer loop is ran:
`for i=(n-1) to 1`. This sets `i` to 4. The loop will run 4 times. The variable `i` in our code represents the number of comparisons to do.
The inner loop is ran:
`for j = 0 to (i-1)` this sets `j` to 0. The loop will run 4 times.
Our if-statement is called:
`if A[j] < A[j+1]` thus comparing indices 0 and 1. `A[0]` holds 5 and `A[1]` holds 9. Since 5 is smaller than 9, our if-statement is true.
`swap(A[j],A[j+1])` is called. Now our array is: `[9,5,2,7,1]`

Our inner-loop runs again, j=1.
Our if-statement compares indices 1 and 2. `A[1]` holds 5 and `A[2]` holds 2. Since 5 is not smaller than 9, our if-statement is false.

Our inner-loop runs again, j=2.
Our if-statement compares indices 2 and 3. `A[2]` holds 2 and `A[3]` holds 7. Since 2 is less than 7, our if-statement is true.
`swap(A[j],A[j+1])` is called. Our array now reads: `[9,5,7,2,1]`

Our inner-loop runs again, j=3.
Our if-statement compares indices 3 and 4. `A[3]` holds 2 and `A[4]` holds 1. Our if-statement is false.

Our inner-loop is complete, we now know that our last-element is **correct**.
So we run our outer loop again. `i` is now 3, since our last element is correct.

We run our inner-loop with j=0. it will run upto `i` which is 3.

`A[0]` holds 9 and `A[1]` holds 5, our if-statement is false.
Next loop, j=1.
A[1] holds 5 and A[2] holds 7. our if-statement is true, so we swap them.
Our array now read:  `[9,7,5,2,1]`
Our logic continues until we're sure our 2nd to last element is **correct**.
After our inner loop completes, we run out outer loop again:
`i` is now 2, the number of comparisons to do.
Our inner-loop fires with j=0 to 1.
Thus we compare indexes 0 with 1 and 1 with 2. Both yield false.
We are now sure that our middle element is **correct**.
`i` is now 1, meaning we do one comparison.
Our inner-loop runs with j=0 to 0:
Thus we compare indexes 0 and 1, since our if-statement is false, we don't swap anything.
Our inner loop completes.
We are now sure our second element is **correct**.
Our outer loop completes.
We are now sure our entire array is **correct**.

---

Our array is now sorted: `[9,7,5,2,1]`

The algorithm also works fine for the worst case scenario:
http://jsfiddle.net/mw5L8qzL/
(an empty array, and an array with only one element included)

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop "bubbles up" the maximum element in the range A[0,...,i] to the slot A[i]. So in the next iteration you can forget about A[i], and restrict the job to sorting A[0,...,i-1].
Clearly when the problem size is one after n-1 iterations of the outer loop, you are left with only one element in the range, so you stop there.